# Magento translate file

Tags: magento

I am want translate magento. I am true translate some string in `\app\locale\en_US`, but I am not see result in admin panel. Why magento not show changed value in `en_US` folder. I am rename `en_US` folder but my site work with english. Why?  I want copy `\app\locale\en_US` to `\app\locale\my_lang` translate. How I can do it, this folder with new translate work to my site.  If I am translate all `\app\locale\my_lang` how I can add to site. And how I can see change during translate..

Answer (score 1):

Have you selectect the right locale in admin (from footer of the page)?

If your translations are for a custom module ensure that you have defined the translation declarations in the `etc/config.xml` (frontend and/or adminhtml areas), otherwise ensure that you have modified the right module's translation file (eg if you have a string 'my string' that is present in `Mage_Customer.csv` and in `Mage_Catalog.csv` you must ensure that you have modified the proper one that is used where you want to see the result).

Also note that you can modify translations in `app/design/package/theme folder`...in a `translate.csv` called file.

The reason you see texts in english even if you delete translations folder is that they are by default passed in code through `__()` function in english. Magento checks if it finds the translation for the current locale in `app/locale/` if it does it shows you that value, otherwise the original string passed to `__()` function is shown.